# Trying to exact copy object "A" location on "x" axis with object "B" following a curve. Both objects need to have matching "x" #'s

Tags: constraints

[image]in the pictures (frames 1, 20, 50, 80, 100), I basically need the red cube and green ball to work as they do, but having the ball as the parent, not child (as shown in suzanne and the cone scenario). The Green Ball (child) and Red Cube (parent) have matching X-axis parameters at all times as they move from left to right. The Blue Cone (child) follows Suzanne (parent), but falls behind and then catches up toward the end of the curve. Both the cube and cone have "clamp-to" constraints on the curves. Any ideas would be great!

[![Frames 1, 20, 50, 80, 100][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: please provide .blend file.

Comment: Chris, .blend file uploaded. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Hi Jim, i deleted my answer after i realized, that you want something, which i don't know how to realize that. I am sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert the curve into a mesh, then add the shrinkwrap modifier to the cone to follow the mesh, AND add a driver to the x axis of the cone to copy the x axis of "var" (which is the x axis location of Suzanne). The copy location modifier on the cone will not work.

[image: curve answer]